# Как узнать качество видео и поменять его с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, видео

Делаю загрузку видео и есть необходимость обрабатывать видео на сервере, для дальнейшей публикации.

После публикации пользователям должно быть доступно несколько качеств видео ( ну 360p, 480p, 720p и т.д) в зависимости от того каким было видео изначально.

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Вы в курсе, что 360p, 480p, 720p это не качество видео, а его размеры?

Comment: @Crantisz я написал так, чтобы было понятно)))

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете *ffmpeg*, команда такая:

```
ffmpeg -i видеофайл
```

Она выводит много строк, интересны строки, описывающие видео и аудио:

```
 Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9838 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
 Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
```

Где размер видео - `1920x1080`, что в данном случае соответствует *1080p* или *FullHD*

Comment: Я знаю как получить размеры, мне нужно сделать копии в разных размерах, а также что делать когда размеры не совсем стандартные?